# Find the dual problem of $\min_x\{||x-a_1||+||x-a_2||+||x-a_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$

Tags: convex-optimization, duality

> Find the dual problem of
> $$\min_x\{||x-a_1||+||x-a_2||+||x-a_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$$

I've tried the following but got stuck
$$\min_x\{||x-a_1||+||x-a_2||+||x-a_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}=\min_{x,z_i}\{||z_1||+||z_2||+||z_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\,z_i=x-a_i\}$$
and the Lagrangian is:\
$L(x,z,\lambda)=  ||z_1||+||z_2||+||z_3||+\sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i(z_i-x+a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{3}z_i\lambda_i+||z_i||-x\sum\lambda_i+\sum\lambda_ia_i$

from $-x\sum\lambda_i$ we can deduce that $\sum \lambda_i=0$ else we get $-\infty$.
Now when I try to solve for each $z_i$ I get $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_i}=\lambda_i+\frac{z_i}{||z_i||}=0$
and I'm not sure how to continue from here.
Any hint?

Comment: This is the Fermat-Torricelli-Steiner Problem whose dual formulation can be found in "Foundations of Optimization" by O. Guler (Springer)

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this is how I'm suppose to solve this :(

Comment: The unweighted case m=3 of minimizing is dual to the construction of the largest equilateral triangle circumscribed to the triangle p1p2p3. [https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fermat-Torricelli_problem]

Comment: @CMichael ok,but how do I solve my problem?(in the way that I've tried)?

Answer (score 1):

$$\min_x\{||x-a_1||+||x-a_2||+||x-a_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}=\min_{x,z_i}\{||z_1||+||z_2||+||z_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\,z_i=x-a_i\}$$
and the Lagrangian is:\
$L(x,z,\lambda)=  ||z_1||+||z_2||+||z_3||+\sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i^T(z_i-x+a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_i^Tz_i+||z_i||-x\sum\lambda_i+\sum\lambda_i^Ta_i$\

From $-x\sum\lambda_i$ we can deduce that $\sum \lambda_i=0$ else we get $-\infty$.
Now when we try to solve for each $z$ we can see it is sperable for each $i$ and minimizing $z_i$ we get the following minimizing problem $\min_{z_i}\lambda_i^Tz_i+||z_i||$  which have finite solution iff $||\lambda_i||\leq1$(seen in class for 1-D case).\
So the dual problem is:\
$$\underset{\lambda_i\in B}{q(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)}=\sum\lambda_i^Ta_i$$
$$B=\{\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_i=0,||\lambda_i||\leq1\}$$